# How to reorder the POST array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form where I am using multidimensional inputs as such `<input type="text" name="input1[]" />`.

I am using JavaScript to programmatically add new rows of inputs into a table like layout. After posting the data I will validate the data and then insert into it into my database.

Currently, I have to iterate like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST[array_keys($_POST)[0]]); $i++) {
    $query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table(col1, col2, col3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
    $a = $_POST["input1"][$i];
    $b = $_POST["input2"][$i];
    $c = $_POST["input3"][$i];
    $query->bind_param("sss", $a, $b, $c);
    $query->execute();
}
```

<sub>**Note:** I have significantly reduced the code to all that is necessary for the question.</sub>

Though, I would prefer to iterate like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST); $i++) {
    $query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table(col1, col2, col3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
    $a = $_POST[$i]["input1"];
    $b = $_POST[$i]["input2"];
    $c = $_POST[$i]["input3"];
    $query->bind_param("sss", $a, $b, $c);
    $query->execute();
}
```

I realise that the two are very similar, but I prefer the latter approach if possible as it seems more clear and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
function neatify_post(&$post)
{
    $tmp = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($post[array_keys($post)[0]]); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($post); $j++) {
            $tmp[$i][array_keys($post)[$j]] = $post[array_keys($post)[$j]][$i];
        }
    }
    return $post = $tmp;
}

neatify_post($_POST);
```

It is not necessary to set $_POST equal to the return of the function as it is [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).